# rsync chmod won't remove executability bit?

Tags: rsync

I'm trying

```
rsync -rltzogvpE --chmod -x,ug=rwX,o= <more_args...>
```

But my files are arriving with the executable bit set.

However, when I do

```
chmod -R -x,ug=rwX,o= .
```

In the same directory, after the upload is complete, the `x` bit is removed off all the files (like I want).

How can I get rsync to remove the `x` bit for me, without issuing a 2nd command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [`rsync` manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html), `rsync --chmod` can take different rules for directories and for files. So if you don't need to consider executable files, but just want the `x`-bit set for directories and unset for files, you should be able to use

```
rsync --chmod D770,F660
```

> In addition to the normal parsing rules specified in the `chmod(1)` manpage, you can specify an item that should only apply to a directory by  prefixing
>                 it with a `D`, or specify an item that should only apply to a file by prefixing it with a `F`.

Didn't test it, though.